# UIL load images in AVD from external urls but doesn't in device

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, android-virtual-device

I'm using [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) to load images from external URLs, it works fine in AVD.

```
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(mContext)); 
imageLoader.displayImage("http://proyectocupones.hol.es/fotos/discount.jpg", holder.image);
```

I check that the UIL lib is in "Java Build Path" and the internet permission in my AndroidManyfest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Any idea where the error might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer for myself:

[Github](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/394)

The error is solved just upgrading the UIL lib (Seems to be a bug of version 1.87)

thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following way to set an image for the player and it worked. Try this way.

```
 ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("Image URL","thumbImageView");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to debug your Phone while connected on the PC and check the logcat to see what is the output and the problem.
Maybe you don't have enabled the internet on phone(?)

Answer (score 0):

Use **Glide** Instead Of UIL Library.